# Special characters (ANSI?) returned by libcurl

Tags: c, utf-8, special-characters, libcurl, windows-1252

I am trying to parse a web page with libcurl in C.

The source webpage looks like this.

> “We don’t have to settle for the limitations of the past.  We can
>   examine and reexamine our old ideas.”

However, when it returns it seems to replace the quotations and apostrophes with special characters and gives me this result:

> �We don�t have to settle for the limitations of the past.  We can
>   examine and reexamine our old ideas.�

I have not run into this and from reading it seems like it's an encoding/charset issue although I am not able to resolve this.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Should this have any effect? If so, or if not, what is the issue and how do I go about resolving this? No other websites I have processed have returned this weird result.

The source URL: http://jftna.org/pages/8-14.htm

Comment: What are the actual byte values used to represent the quotation marks in the source webpage?

Comment: Lib curl doesn't interpret your HTML, so that tag will not have any affect. It is better to have the server send the appropriate HTTP headers, which libcurl *can* interpret.

Comment: This page is only available in that charset, I believe.

Comment: if you know what char set it is you could convert it to utf or something, 0x93 is outside of ascii... 0x0-0x7f

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are better ways to do this but I decided for ease to just replace the hex value.

```
out = replace_all( out, "\x93", "\"");
```

Thanks for reading and if there are any better ways I would be glad to hear it!